# When i try to login in my server app with Phone and password it show "User does not exist in Database" I have my Database in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When i try to login in my server app with Phone and password it show "User does not exist in Database" I have my Database in `firebase` .
But the problem is that i have already checked my database name, password which is same value as in my Java file in Android Studio

My database-

```
"user" : {

    "098223445" : {
      "Name" : "Garvit",
      "Password" : "1234",
        "IsStaff" : "false"
    },
    "0982234543" : {
      "Name" : "Anurag",
      "Password" : "1234",
         "IsStaff" : "false"
    },
     "0912" : {
      "name" : "Abhi",
      "password" : "1234",
       "IsStaff" : "true"
    }
  }
}
```

---

My Android Studio Java file-
this LogIn.java

```
package com.kafeno.kafenopartner;

    public class LogIn extends AppCompatActivity {

        EditText edtPhone, edtPassword;
        Button btnLogIn;

        FirebaseDatabase db;
        DatabaseReference users;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);

            edtPassword = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
            edtPhone = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtphone);
            btnLogIn =  (FButton)findViewById(R.id.btnLogIn);


            //Init Firebase
            db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            users = db.getReference("User");

            btnLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    logInUser(edtPhone.getText().toString(),edtPassword.getText().toString());
                }
            });

        }

        private void logInUser( String phone, String password) {
         final  ProgressDialog mDialog  = new ProgressDialog(LogIn.this);
            mDialog.setMessage("Please waiting...");
            mDialog.show();

            final String localPhone = phone;
            final String localPassword = password;
            users.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.child(localPhone).exists())
                    {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        User user = dataSnapshot.child(localPhone).getValue(User.class);
                        user.setPhone(localPhone);
                        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(user.getIsStaff())) // If isStaff  == true
                        {
                            if(user.getPassword().equals(localPassword))
                            {
                                //Login ok
                            }
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "Wrong password !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "Please login with Staff account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "User not exist in Database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/

Go with Firebase Auth instead of firebase database for User Related functions.

Comment: Thanks for answer but Firebase Auth is for auth of E-mail or Phone no and    In this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2yKxB4wJR4&t=769s, This person did login for app with Firebase only.